# Starting Activity from other Class

Tags: android

Google map is displayed here and I also want to issue notification and when I click it, notification should take me to the main activity ie, google map but notification is not issued . Here are 2 classes and manifest file.

```
  public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity{


protected GoogleMap gMap;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    if (gMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Google Maps not available",           
         Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();           
    gMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    }           
  }
```

Notify Class,

```
    public class Notify extends Activity {

@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.jollyr)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setContentTitle("Flood Warning")
            .setContentText("You are in Danger Zone");


    // Sets an ID for the notification
    int notId = 001;
    // Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Builds the notification and issues it.
    mNotifyMgr.notify(notId, mBuilder.build());



    Intent i=new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
            this,
            0,
            i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );  
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);             


  }
  }
```

Manifest file,

```
   <application
     android:allowBackup="true"
     android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

     <activity
        android:name="com.example.map.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>

      <activity
            android:name="com.example.map.Notify"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.map.Notify" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
        android:name="Package+.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Key here" />

     </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: where do you navigate to `Notify` activity?

Comment: you are not navigating to `Notify` activity. your notification is displayed there. There is no click listener in your `MainActivity`. So your notification is not displayed.

Comment: So i have to make a click listener in MainActivity ? which will open the Notify class !

Comment: yes something like clicking on the map display notification

Comment: No no, notification is displayed as the map is displayed. but when notification is clicked then map is displayed only not notification again.

Comment: why do you have `Notify` Activity move your notification code in `onCreate` of `MainActivity`.

Comment: Still I have to apply geofences and lot of stuff so I made separate class for issuing notifications and did not write it's code in oncreate of MainActivity. So kindly tell me why notification is not issued ??

Comment: it will not cause you do not navigate to `Notify` activity where you have code for notification. How did you imagine notification will be displayed?

Comment: Basically i want the App to issue notification when user passes by a geofence !  so I should write code for notification and geofence in onCreate of MainActivity ??   And what r my other options ??

Comment: you need to decide what you want but with the current code posted your notification will not be displayed. Yes move the code to oncreate of MainActivity and see yourself.

Comment: having functionality in separate class is fine. But each activity class has its own ui and lifecycle. So having functionality in different class is fine but having it in a activity class is different. You have got confused from a Plain java class with Activity class

Comment: wow............ !   Me cleared now , Amazing Sir :)